# Shiny reactive function is not updating as expected

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

**Original question posted here:** [Shiny reactive Unexpected Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27478028/shiny-reactive-unexpected-behavior)
The question is being re-posted here in an attempt to improve the original question posted previously in the link provided above as I was not able to receive any assistance.

**Objective:** In brief, the purpose of this app is to allow the user to perform search, filter, and slice and dice the data, provided in from of a dataframe, based on various inputs provided to the user.

As part of the `server` function, a reactive function named `index` has been defined to look up the indices corresponding to the user's inputs. The reactive function,`index`, uses `grep` and `which` functions to locate the respective indices in the dataframe `df`.

I have included a reproducible code and tried to include comments, where appropriate.

**Further explanation about the code:**
The title of this question is just my own speculation and it's based on the assumption that the code within `index` is correct. there might be a fundamental issue with the code within `index` and not the reactivity of the `index` function necessarily. In order to test this, as part of the `server` function, I have included a function `printIndex` in order to print the results of `index` to make sure that it works properly.

I have personally tried printing the results of `ind.j`, `ind.c`, `ind.l`,`ind.d`, `ind.s`, and `ind.all` each one individually to the console and they seemed to all produce the right results. However, when I test the results of `ind` it's not quite what I expect so I'm wondering if it's the reactivity or the line of code that's problematic. What the `ind` intends to do is to take the list of all the looked-up indices, stored in `ind.all`, and applies the `intersect` function recursively to find the common elements from all the sublists in `ind.all`.

As I mentioned above, the `index` function works fine for individual filters. However, when I enter values for all the indices, as a user, the function does not update to the correct list of indices as expected. For example, you can try inputting "application" in the **Job** textInput, "Gas Drive Global" in the **Company** selectizeInput, and "Calgary" in the **Location** textInput at the same time and hit **Search!**. You will see that the data table does not return any results while this clearly corresponds to the 1st row of the dataframe `df`.

```
#Load required packages
ListofPackages= c('shiny','ggplot2','scales')
lapply(ListofPackages,require,character.only=TRUE)

#Define the dataframe on which the search will be performed
df <- data.frame(Job=c('Applications Engineer Ã¢â¬â Gas Drive',
                       'Engineer, Operations',
                       'Project Engineer',
                       'Project Engineer (Oil & Gas)',
                       'Project Engineer',
                       'Junior Engineer',
                       'Engineer, Operations',
                       'Research and Development (R&D) Junior Engineer',
                       'JUNIOR QUALITY ENGINEER',
                       'Junior Systems Design and Support Engineer',
                       'Mechanical Engineer Calgary, AB',
                       'Applications Engineer',
                       'Project Engineer',
                       'Pipeline Engineer',
                       'Development Engineer',
                       'Specialist Engineering Finance',
                       'Mechanical Engineer - Sudbury',
                       'Project Cost Analyst (12 month term)',
                       'Project Controls Functional Analyst',
                       'Project Controls Professionals'),
             Company=c('Gas Drive Global',
                       'Agrium Wholesale',
                       'City of Calgary',
                       'Stantec',
                       'Shell',
                       'Canadian National Railway',
                       'Pembina Pipeline Corporation',
                       'Velan Inc.',
                       'G.W. Goudreau Personnel Services Ltd',
                       'Stratified Automotive Controls',
                       'Pason Systems Corp.',
                       'Howden',
                       'Plains Midstream Canada',
                       'Amec Foster Wheeler',
                       'Red Bend Software',
                       'Canadian Pacific',
                       'GENIVAR',
                       'Thales',
                       'AltaGas Ltd.','BEMAC Construction Corp.'),
            Location=c('Calgary',
                      'Redwater',
                      'Calgary',
                      'Edmonton',
                      'Sarnia',
                      'MontrÃ©al',
                      'Calgary',
                      'MontrÃ©al',
                      'Windsor',
                      'Vancouver',
                      'Calgary',
                      'Winnipeg',
                      'Calgary',
                      'Calgary',
                      'Engineer',
                      'Calgary',
                      'Greater Sudbury',
                      'Ottawa',
                      'Calgary',
                      'Calgary'),
              Posted=c(1,
                       1,
                       1,
                       2,
                       2,
                       1,
                       4,
                       5,
                       6,
                       4,
                       1,
                       5,
                       5,
                       3,
                       1,
                       1,
                       15,
                       1,
                       1,
                       13),
             Source=c('Indeed',
                      'Indeed',
                      'Indeed',
                      'Indeed',
                      'Indeed',
                      'Indeed',
                      'Indeed',
                      'Indeed',
                      'Indeed',
                      'Indeed',
                      'Indeed',
                      'Indeed',
                      'Indeed',
                      'Indeed',
                      'Indeed',
                      'Indeed',
                      'Indeed',
                      'Indeed',
                      'Indeed',
                      'Indeed'),
                url=c('http://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=2371e16aab902f84',
                      'http://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=428facb738edd397',
                      'http://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=e15d8fe4d362279b',
                      'http://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=28c1464fd4e28b24',
                      'http://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=736ec57bf6902b93',
                      'http://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=bdc9999eae922645',
                      'http://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=3a4588fca0e600b1',
                      'http://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=71f1abcd100850c6',
                      'http://ca.indeed.com/cmp/G.W.Goudreau-Personnel-Services-Ltd/jobs/Junior-Quality-Engineer-3237601a1f3d3abc?r=1',
                      'http://ca.indeed.com/cmp/Stratified-Automotive-Controls/jobs/Junior-System-Design-Support-Engineer-1d916a435e69b8ce?r=1',
                      'http://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=fca9a784a37ece8a',
                      'http://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=b2d0975c638c03a8',
                      'http://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=c92725272c5f9ced',
                      'http://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=cd97c050df64787c',
                      'http://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=e6e278ed52532f73',
                      'http://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=a1f14d52c7798d7b',
                      'http://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=112350d5e020241f',
                      'http://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=a324c2dcade7dc5c',
                      'http://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=77895efdf28ad6fa',
                      'http://ca.indeed.com/cmp/BEMAC-Construction-Corp./jobs/Project-Control-Professional-90796e764f064a51?r=1'))

server <- function(input,output,session){

    #Server-side search for the choices argument of selectizeInput in ui.R
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'c', choices = as.character(df$Company), server = TRUE)

    #Create a reactive function to look up the indices correponding to the user's inputs
    index <- reactive({
        ind.j <- if(input$j=='') NULL else grep(input$j,df[,'Job'],ignore.case = T)
        ind.c <- {tmp<-lapply(input$c, function(x) {which(df[,'Company']==x)}); Reduce(union,tmp)}
        ind.l <- if(input$l=='') NULL else grep(input$l,df[,'Location'],ignore.case = T)
        ind.d <- which(df[,'Posted']<=input$d)
        ind.s <- {tmp<-lapply(input$s, function(x) {which(df[,'Source']==x)}); Reduce(union,tmp)}
        ind.all <- list(ind.j,ind.c,ind.l,ind.d,ind.s)
        ind <- if(is.null(ind.s)) NULL else {ind.null<- which(lapply(ind.all,is.null)==TRUE) ;Reduce(intersect,ind.all[-ind.null])}

    })

    #Create a reactive function to return the search results by returning the indices looked up in the index function above
    search <- reactive({

              df[index(),]

    })

    #Print the results of the index function above to test if it works properly
    output$printIndex <- renderUI({
           list(index())
    })

    #Send the searchresult table to ui.R to print the results of the search function above
    output$searchresult <- renderDataTable({
        input$action6   #triggered only when button is pressed
        if(input$action6==0) return() 
        else{isolate({
            transformed <- transform(search(), Link = paste('<a href = ', shQuote(url), '>', 'Click</a>'))
            transformed <- transformed[,c(1:3,5,7,4,6)] #Rearrange columns
            transformed[-7] #Remove last column
        })
        }
    }, option=list(autoWidth=FALSE,pageLength=100,
                   columnDefs = list(list(targets =c(5,6) -1, searchable = FALSE),list(sWidth=c("100px")))))


}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

    #Display datatable filters on top
    tags$head(tags$style("tfoot {display: table-header-group;}")),        

    #Add a title
    h1('Power Search'),

    #Use the Sidebar layout
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(

            #Add various fields for the user in order to search the dataframe  
                     h5('Note: Running the app takes a little while at startup.'),
                     helpText('Job:'),
                     textInput('j',''),
                     helpText('Company:'),
                     selectizeInput('c','',choices=NULL,multiple=T),
                     helpText('Location:'),
                     textInput('l',''),
                     sliderInput('d','Posted (days ago)',min = 0,max = 60,step = 5,value = 60),
                     checkboxGroupInput('s','',choices = c('Indeed','Glassdoor'),selected = c('Indeed','Glassdoor')),
                     actionButton('action6','Search!')
        ),


        mainPanel(

            #Display results
            htmlOutput('printIndex'),
            dataTableOutput('searchresult')
        )      

    )
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is with the `which` function:

```
> which(rep(FALSE, 5))
integer(0)
```

You can change:

```
ind <- if(is.null(ind.s)){
  NULL
}else{
  ind.null<- which(lapply(ind.all,is.null)==TRUE)
  Reduce(intersect,ind.all[-ind.null])
}
```

to

```
ind <- if(is.null(ind.s)){
  NULL
}else{
  Reduce(intersect,ind.all[!sapply(ind.all,is.null)])
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot John!! So I guess the problem was the case where `ind.null` = 0 and so `ind.all[-0]` won't work. and the workaround, as you suggested, is to subset `ind.all` with a logical vector as opposed to a numeric vector. Does that confirm my understanding here?

Comment: `integer(0)` is an empty integer vector rather than `0L`. Negating an empty integer vector has no effect. Subsetting using an empty integer vector will return an empty result.

Comment: As a follow up to this question and reference to the question previously posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325855/shiny-error-arguments-imply-differing-number-of-rows), please try unchecking "Indeed" or try any other combination which results in a 0-row dataframe and then hit Search and see what happens. I was told that this error has been resolved in the shiny development version but I tried it with the development version and I still got the same error. Can you shed some light as to what might be causing the issue for the 0-row cases?

Comment: Your data.frame is empty. `paste('<a href = ', shQuote(search()$url), '>', 'Click</a>')` however returns `"<a href =  \"\" > Click</a>"`. You are then trying to bind this new column with one row to your data.frame with no rows. Hence the error message.

Comment: Amazing observation! I've been stuck with this app for a while now and I got my problems solved in just a few minutes, thanks to you. Many many appreciations!!

Comment: @BahaeOmid I added a fix to return a `character(0)` when you have an empty `data.frame`.